# PopUp a Modal using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I want to popup my login modal on Search click if loginStatus == false, using jQuery.

I.e. if user is not logged in, I want him to login first.

```
        $('#serviceSelect').on('click', function(event) {
        if (found == 0) {
            alert("Sorry donot exist")
        }
        if(found ==1)
            {
            var status=sessionStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
            //alert(status);
            if(status==true){
                alert("Logged in");

            /*--------------    Specify the Questionnare link here -------------*/
            }
            else{
                alert("Logged out");
                /*$('#serviceSelect').attr('data-target','#login-modal');*/

                var modal = $("#login-modal");
                modal.style.display = "block";
            }
            }
         });
```

This is the list item which popus the login if user wants to login by himself .

```
       <li class="sidebar-brand" id="loginref"><a href="#"
                data-toggle="modal" data-target="#login-modal"
                data-backdrop="static">
```

Login Modal div:

```
    <div class="modal fade" id="login-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
    aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true"
    style="display: none;">
```

Update:

This is popping the modal, but the js of the modal is not attached with the modal.

i.e, There is a login.js which executes on login modal.
By popping modal using this, that js is not being executed.

```
         modal.modal('show');
```

Comment: did you add the boostrap css and script to your page

Comment: Have you tried attaching an event handler to the modal's `shown.bs.modal` event and executing your login.js code in the handler?

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$('#login-modal').modal('show');
```

Comment: Modal is popping up. But the js of the modal is not executing

Comment: load the js when the page is loaded

Answer (score 1):

Use bootstrap `.modal('show');`

```
$('#serviceSelect').on('click', function(event) {
        if (found == 0) {
            alert("Sorry donot exist")
        }
        if(found ==1)
            {
            var status=sessionStorage.getItem('isLoggedIn');
            //alert(status);
            if(status==true){
                alert("Logged in");

            /*--------------    Specify the Questionnare link here -------------*/
            }
            else{
                alert("Logged out");
                /*$('#serviceSelect').attr('data-target','#login-modal');*/

                var modal = $("#login-modal");
                modal.modal('show');
            }
            }
         });
```

mote info on [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modal-show)

Comment: Modal is popping up. But the js of the modal is not executing.